# Case Sensitive Url

Tags: uri

I have some issues with the url's while doing the migration to new site.

content has following url after migration - www.example.com/attachment/Att.doc

But attachment folder has **att.doc**.so the url is not working properly due to case sensitive issue.

I tried use checkspelling On Apache server but it didn't work.

Please let me know if there is a different solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could [permit case-insensitive URLs](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/108-how-to-permit-case-insensitive-urls-with-apache/).

Comment: Beth,Thanks for reply.I tried this in /var/www/html/drupal/.htaccess file it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try troubleshooting such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450032/apache-mod-speling-case-insensitive-urls-issue

Comment: If you just want help troubleshooting how to make Apache accept case-insensitive URLs, that belongs on a different forum. It sounds like Drupal is not really the problem by itself.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on what happened?  Did you have a Drupal dev site that everything worked fine on, and now is broken when you went live?  Or, was this with another type of migration?